# Unable to get Not Visible Individually products magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, products

I am using DI

```
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
```

in my class and get all products using

```
$collect = $this->collectionFactory->create()->getItems();
```

but when i need to filter specific category products using

```
$collect->addCategoryFilter($child_detail)
```

those products with **VISIBILTY** = ***Not Visible Individually*** do not appear in my search only **VISIBILITY**=***Catalog, Search*** products appear.

kindly help thanks in advance.

Comment: that will create issue for user....@PrathapGunasekaran

Comment: but this is only way to all products by search and what do you mean by issue for users @AsadUllah

Comment: i mean when user look in search bar for a product let suppose "Erika Running Short" he will also get this products child in search bar like "Erika Running Short-32-Red" and other child products

Comment: and if he clicks on child product that URL doesn't exit that will create a problem

Comment: No the product won't go for 404 if the product VISIBILITY sets to search only in the sense, it will be visible only on search not on category listing. It doesn't mean that product URL won't exist and hope you get the point here

Answer (score 0):

After digging on this particular question i have found if we use a custom query in our controller we can get all product including parent products and child-products all in one.
Inject this to controller

```
 \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
```

Create object in **__construct**

```
$this->_resources = $resourceConnection;
```

In your **Function** use

```
$connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
                     $select = $connection->select()
                         ->from(['o' =>  $this->_resources->getTableName('catalog_category_product')]);
                     $select->where('category_id = ?', 'add your category id' here);

                     $result = $connection->fetchAll($select);
```

We get Category products ids in ***$result*** and now for using Product_id separately use foreach and save

```
$proIds = array();
                     foreach ($result as $product)
                     {
                         $proIds[] = $product['product_id'];
                     }
```

Then inject ***\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory*** class and use it with ***$this->productCollectionFactory*** to filter your products from all products.

```
$collect = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
                         ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in',$proIds));
```

Use ***foreach*** to deal with products separately

```
 foreach ($collect as $Product)
                     {
                         ***"Do what ever you want with product"***
                     }
```

If that helps hit like thanks